# How to implement muti file upload(with partial remove) in spring 4.x with jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to implement a bbs with Spring and jsp.

Found some multi-file upload example but I need some extra functions(canceling)

I am looking forward an example with below conditions.

1. Users can upload multi files
2. Users can cancel upload a file(or files) which has already registered.
3. All of these happen in same page without refreshing.

what I am trying to build looks like below

```
filename1.ext  ('x' button) 
filename2.ext  ('X' button) 
(input tag with file type)
```

if press x button the file in same row will be dropped.

What I need is just simple example or hints.

Thanks so much in advanced:D

===================================================

It more likely below link:

http://milladdagdoni.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/spring-mvc-upload-multiple-files/

has one input tag for multiple files,

but in my case, I have to show list.

Follow is little progress of my work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Multi file upload test</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Upload Files
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
<form id="fileForm" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
         <table id="fList">
         </table>
    </div>
    <!-- 
    <input name="inFile" type="file" onchange="javascript:restoreFile()">
     -->
    <input name="inFile" type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="javascript:restoreFile()">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
<h4><a href="#" onclick="javascript:location.href='/upload'"><b>upload.jsp</b></a></h4>
</body>
<script>
    function restoreFile(){
        var fileName = $("input[name='inFile']").val();
        var fileNameWithoutPath = getSeparatedFileName('name', fileName);
        var abFileName = fileNameWithoutPath.split('.')[0];

        if(fileName != null && fileName.length > 0){
            var close_btn = "<button>";
            $('#fList').append("<tr id='" +  abFileName + "'><td>" + fileNameWithoutPath + "</td>" + 
                    "<td><a href='#' id='" +  abFileName + "_rm'>remove</a></td></tr>");

            $('#' + abFileName + '_rm').on("click", function(e){
                $('#' + abFileName).remove();
            });
        }
    }

    function getSeparatedFileName(type, fileName){
        var fileNames = fileName.split('\\');
        if(type == 'name'){
            return fileNames[fileNames.length - 1];
        }else if(type == 'path'){
            var endIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('\\');
            return fileName.substring(0, endIndex);
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I had tried jquery to show file list. If I do not use multiple="multiple" in input tag, it works. However, after adding that it shows the first member and count only.

Thanks for many help:D

Answer (score 0):

I had seen a good example in the following site for [multiple file upload](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multiple-file-upload-example/) option . But it is for Spring 3

It also demonstrates addition of files , mainly file input fields.

> if press x button the file in same row will be dropped.

You can try it using `jquery` to drop a row on button click events.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for fast answer :D bb However it is little different with what I wanted. I need a file list in output page and interact with it.(and want to use only one input tag). Anyway thanks for helping me. I thinks it is very common type of implementation, so I believe there are just right examples or tutorials:)

Comment: i am sorry if i couldnt specifically help you ;(

Answer (score 0):

This is the best plugin for JQuery that I found, it was so usefull that I donate money to the guy, take a look, it does all that you´re looking for and more.

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Comment: Thanks. But can not use unofficial plugin.